# Calling a method that belongs to a child component from a component that sits in a parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call a method in a child component from a component that sits on the paerent component. Please see below:

App class

```
    //    App.js 
    class App extends Component {
          render() {
            return (
              <div className="App">
                  <SimpleModal/>
                <FloatingButton onClick={/*would like to call HandleOpen in SimpleModal*/}/> 
              </div>
            );
          }
        }

        export default App;
```

And here's that SimpleModal component

```
//SimpleModal
    class SimpleModal extends React.Component {
      state = {
        open: false,
      };

      handleOpen = () => {
        this.setState({ open: true });
      };

      handleClose = () => {
        this.setState({ open: false });
      };

      render() {
        return (
            <Modal
              aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
              aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
              open={this.state.open}
              onClose={this.handleClose}
            >
              <div style={getModalStyle()}>
                <Typography type="title" id="modal-title">
                  Text in a modal
                </Typography>
                <Typography type="subheading" id="simple-modal-description">
                  Description
                </Typography>
              </div>
            </Modal>
        );
      }
    }

    export default SimpleModal;
```

Basically I would like to call HandleOpen and HandleCall from FloatingButton. How should I do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define both functions in the parent component (`<App />`) and pass them to the child via `props`. This way both `<FloatingButton>` and `<SimpleModal>` can have access to the same function. This technique is called "lift state up" and [there is a very good article about it](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the functions from a sibling component, you could **lift the state to the common parent component**.

This allows you to pass the event handler into the `FloatingButton` component, and the current state of the modal into the `Modal` component.

---

For more infos, check out the [relevant section in the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html):

> Often, several components need to reflect the same changing data. We recommend lifting the shared state up to their closest common ancestor.